# How do you initialise Nested Structures and run methods within nested structures in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, class, swift, struct

I have a Class. The class has variables which are structures and some of these structures have structures as variables with methods.

When I run the program and debug through I can see that my class variables but the variable which is a struct is just nil.

I have included all the class definitions and struct definitions as screen shots and my call and debug screen... Any help would be great.

Trying to call

CLASS--> Struct(Details)-->Struct(Location)-->StructMethod(ConfigLocation)

Ok here are the screen shots.

and code.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please paste the code instead of screen shots. So that, answers can easily try and modify your code in their environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
struct SV_StinkDetails_Model {

    // ...

    var SV_StinkDetails_Location:SV_StinkLocation_Model! = SV_StringLocation_Model()
    //...                                                    Just remove `?` here ^
```

`SV_StinkLocation_Model?()` means `Optional<SV_StinkLocation_Model>()`. That returns `nil` with `SV_StinkLocation_Model?` type.

Comment: This did assist and got me past the first roadblock.. I can now see inside Details. However It gives me an error on my call to Location now saying that its expecting the variables inside my location as part of the call to the create location struct?

var SV_StinkDetails_Location:SV_StinkLocation_Model! = SV_StinkLocation_Model()

gives me error: Missing Argument  SV_StinkLocation_Longitude in call? 

SV_StinkLocation_Longitude is a variable in the struct SV_StinkLocation. 

If i remove that variable it gives me the same error for the next variable?! @rintaro ?